# Incomplete data from Online MySqlDatabase to DataTable

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to save an online MySql database to a local Sqlite database. What I do is, try to get whole data from MySql to a datatable then from the datatable save it to the Sqlite. So, I tried to make sure that I get all the data from the MySql first counting the datatable through "Console.printLine".

The problem is, when I count the data in the PhpMyAdmin of the MySql, using `SELECT COUNT(REFENCE)` I get a count of 83,335 rows but in my Console.WriteLine, using the increment +1, I only get up to 3,857 rows which made me to believe that what I am getting is incomplete. Can you show me where I am wrong. If you have better way of copying then Online MySql "table" data to Sqlite table that would be great. Thank you.

```
private void buttonX1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const string sql1 =
          @"SELECT reference, DATE(trx_date) as 'date', chassis_nmbr, status, remarks, 
            approved_by, DATE(date_approved), branch_code FROM jobcomp_hdr;";
    var table = new DataTable("onlineData");
    using (var conn = new DwoAccess().ConnectToMySql())
    {
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql1, conn))
        {
            try
            {
                 cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                 var adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                 conn.Open();
                 adapt.Fill(table);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 //ignore
             }
         }
     }
     var x=0;
     foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(row["reference"].ToString());
          x += 1;
     }
     Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why not clearing console, for example when `x==1000`? You can use `Console.Clear()`. Or use `Debug.WriteLine("text");` when you run program in debug mode you will see messages in output window

Comment: My point is not really on seeing what is being written in the console but the count that is generated in the console. It only shows 3,857 but the data in my online database is 83,335. This means that only 3,857 of the 83,335 has been downloaded to the "datatable".

Comment: You get any exception?

Comment: Yes. It's the I/O error. I guess it's when the download is taking too long. But that's the reason I made the command.timeout = 60.

Comment: How long does the query take?  If it takes less than 60 seconds then you should have all of your data or there is something wrong with you query.  But as you are not doing anything with the exception then you might not realise it!   Also, how does the table.Rows.Count compare to your manual count of rows in your loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with time of executing query and timeout, number of all rows is to big and executing it is to long. So You  can use `LIMIT` where you set number  rows to skip and number rows to get. Using `for` loop and quantity of all rows in table you will be able take tables divided into several parts 1,000 items in this case.

Here you find more about `LIMIT` in mysql ,[samples](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rowsNumberInTable; i = i + 1000)
{
    ...
    string sql1 =@"SELECT reference, DATE(trx_date) as 'date', chassis_nmbr, status, remarks, approved_by, DATE(date_approved), branch_code FROM jobcomp_hdr LIMIT " + i + @" ," + i+ 1000;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're right, It is for the reason that it takes too long to download because of the file size. But what I just did is ask the user to filter the data between dates only. But your suggestion in right and I would try that...